# "Time Ago" addon that has multilanguage support

Tags: multi-language, time

I am using this [addon](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nic) to show time in a "time ago" format. The problem with this one is that it doesn't seem to support multilanguage.

Is there an add-on or a PHP solution that supports this kind of feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you would like to show the Date (like day, month name) in different languages. Right?
If you are using language pack for multi-language then you can change those into language file   "system\expressionengine\language\english\core_lang.php". This is for English, you can do same for other language.

Comment: My current path of action is to just add a language folder to the addon and utilize that to translate the output. I just wanted to see some more information on this matter because I might have missed an addon or solution that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Time / date values seem to be hardcoded in English in the plugin code.

A few things you can try:

1. Ping the dev [on github](https://github.com/pvledoux/Nice_time.ee2_addon) or via email (look at the source code)
2. As a temporary solution you could use Low Replace (or something similar) to replace some text in English by its equivalent in whatever language you need.

Code:

```
{exp:low_replace find="on|1 day ago|([0-9]+) days ago" replace="le|il y a 1 jour|il y a $1 jours" multiple="yes" regex="yes"}
    {exp:nice_time date="{entry_date}" format="%d-%m-%Y"}
{/exp:low_replace}
```